# Move to different tab controller index from different class

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am having this problem for quite awhile, I have a slider menu use third party library, and I have an option to move to different indexSelected for the tab bar but it is in the different class.

AppDelegate.swift

```
var main: FirstViewController = FirstViewController()

func getMain() -> FirstViewController{
    return main
}
```

SliderMenuViewController.swift

```
slideMenuController()?.closeLeftNonAnimation()
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1 ) {
     let abc: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
     let tst = abc.getMain()
     tst.moveTab()
```

FirstViewController.swift

```
func moveTab(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        }
    }
```

Comment: use notification centre

Comment: Why is your `moveTab()` code wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async {`? Unless you're calling from a background thread, this is _not_ required

Comment: @AshleyMills I thought I needed it because it must be handled in the main thread, because it was not working, so I added it, but still no difference.

Comment: @SPatel could you give a simple example?

Comment: in tabar controller start listening fit tab event and in Any other controller u can post event

Comment: @SPatel alright, thanks mate.

Comment: In moveTab, print out self.tabBarController and check it's not nil. If it is nil, share the code where you set up the rootViewController.